# Physical meaning behind causal massless scalar propogator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

I know that for a scalar massless field in $(3+1)$ spacetime that:
$$
\langle 0 | \phi(x) \phi(y) | 0 \rangle \propto |x-y|^{-2} = (-(t_x-t_y)^2 + (\vec{x}-\vec{y})^2)^{-1}.
$$
 I also know that 
$$
G_R(x-y) = \theta(t_x-t_y) \langle 0| \left[ \phi(x) \phi(y) \right] | 0 \rangle.
$$
 But these two pieces of information seem to imply that 
$$
 G_R(x-y) \propto \theta(t_x-t_y) |x-y|^{-2} - \theta(t_x-t_y) |y-x|^{-2} = 0,
$$
which, to me at least, doesn't seem to make physical sense. I would have thought that at least on the light cone that the causal [propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Relativistic_propagators) would be nonzero. So my question is: which is incorrect: my math or my physical intuition?

Comment: There is also an $\epsilon$ perscription you omitted in the expression of the two point function: $t_x-t_y -i\epsilon$. This avoids your wrong result.

Comment: Thanks! I set $\epsilon \to 0$ too soon then... Just to make sure I understand, this gives $G_R \propto \epsilon |x-y|^{-2}$. So then the propagator is zero except on the lightcone, where then the denominator lets the propogator $\to \infty$ as $\sim x^{-2}$, which overpowers the $\epsilon$ term.

Comment: ...yes, it is so!